# networkx graph drawing and connection making

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, networkx

here is my question.

**The Problem:**

I have a list of products which are connected which each other. Unfortunetly I just have the imediate connection which each other which looks like this:

> sku, related_sku
>
> M-blabla-1,   M-blabla-C
>
> M-blabla-3,   M-blabla-C
>
> M-xxxx-1, M-xxxx-2

etc. the list is long, like 18.000 rows.

**My Solution so far:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv as csv
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx_viewer import Viewer


data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxxx.yyyyy\Downloads\tryanderror.csv', error_bad_lines=False, sep=';')

g = nx.Graph()

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    g.add_edge(row['sku'],row['related_sku'])

nx.connected_component_subgraphs(g)
```

and **now I don't know where to go from here.**

It would be awesome if you could help

**What I need:**

- a list of all the connections

  e.g. SKU: A is connected with SKU B, T and F
- a graph like this: [image]

**Thanks for the help**

Comment: This is a bit broad, you seem to already have code to add the edges and you should be able to draw a graph and determine all the nodes connected to your node either using pandas methods or after constructing a nx graph and calling `edges` on a specific node

Comment: List is simply: `edge_list = G.edges()` and for drawing you will need to change labels to make them appear as letters but you will still be able the graph with `nx.draw_networkx` function. I might be able to help with that but I do not  get how do you know the edge weights also the node labels